# CSS How to make a DIV that starts 100px from the top reach the bottom of the page

Tags: css

I've read through several pages of questions, but I haven't been able to solve my problem. I'm pretty sure this is an extremely simple question, and I am really sorry if I waste anyone's time, but I just can't figure this out. I'm not going to post my actual code, because I think a general answer will be faster. My page is simple, nothing fancy at all, it's setup like this:

[image: CSS example]

The entire page is wrapped in a container. The problem I'm having, is i can't make the left column reach the bottom of the page. I've tried height:100%; but it creates a scroll bar because the top bar is 228px in height. I've tried giving the left column a height:100%; and margin-bottom:-228px; but that didn't work either. I've seen this on websites before, and I'm guessing I'm going to get flak because I SHOULD know this, but can I blame it on the cold that I have? Anyway, thanks for any help that I get!

Comment: In all honesty it might be a good idea to post your code. The answer depends on what you've set the position attribute of the parent container to.

Comment: I had originally posted my code, but this page is part of a much larger project, and the CSS files all intertwine, and it would have been WAY too much. It's mostly my fault, I wasn't writing my CSS with this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

#left-column, #right-column { 
   height: 100%;
}
```

Setting the `<html>` and `<body>` element (as a group selector) to a `display: block` then stretch it out by 100%, the child elements can inherit what is known as a 100% `height`, otherwise, the browser doesn't know what to reference.

You could also make your columns absolutely positioned, then add a `top:100px; bottom:0` (**untested**)

Comment: position:absolute; top:100px; bottom: 0; --> never fails!, take care of previous containers with position: relative;

Comment: Yes!! This worked! And now I feel like an idiot. Specifically, the absolute positioning, with the top set to whatever, and the bottom set to 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/awuvuCO/1)

CSS from example:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%; /* THAT IS IMPORTANT */
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}

#left{
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%; /* THAT IS IMPORTANT */
}

#right{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;  /* THAT IS IMPORTANT */
}
```

Comment: This produces the same problem I have, since the top bar has a fixed width, the page scrolls. I was basically wanting the left bar (the right bar doesn't have to) take up the entire height of the page if the content in that box doesn't extend that far, so there's no gap from the left bar to the bottom. Thanks though.